# y values doesn't match the xticks in pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to draw a simple plot with error bar. So I used `plt.errorbar` function. But the x-axis order was alphabetical order but I wanted to change it, I used `plt.xticks` function to designate the location of the x values. But the result is, `xticks` changed the order as I intended but the y values remained the same, which doesn't match the x value now.

At start I used python list to x and y, but I changed it to `numpy` array, but results were the same.

```
x = ['Andy', 'Red', 'Norton', 'Heywood', 'Tommy', 'DA','Bogs', 'Brooks', 'Skeet']
x = np.array(x)
y = np.array([1.298028801,1.189740519,0.848361823,1.636059322,1.026463944,
              1.319936042,1.539851181,1.527549508,0.979018094])
error = np.array(y)

plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr=1.96*error, fmt='o', capsize=4, color= 'tomato')
plt.xlabel('character', size=15)
plt.ylabel('counts', size=15)

plt.xticks(range(len(x)), x)

plt.show()
```

[image: res]

I wanted the same order of x and y, but after I designated `plt.xticks`, it didn't match the order, which is originally

```
'Andy':1.2980,'Red':1.1897,'Norton':0.8483, ...
```

Comment: Upgrade to any matplotlib version >=2.2 and remove the `xticks` line.

Comment: You were right. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the matplotlib version 3.0.2:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = ['Andy', 'Red', 'Norton', 'Heywood', 'Tommy', 'DA','Bogs', 'Brooks', 'Skeet']
x = np.array(x)
y = [1.298028801,1.189740519,0.848361823,1.636059322,1.026463944,1.319936042,1.539851181,1.527549508,0.979018094]
np.array([1.189740519,0.848361823,1.636059322,1.026463944,1.319936042,1.539851181,1.527549508,0.979018094])
error = np.array(y)

plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr=1.96*error, fmt='o', capsize=4, color= 'tomato')
plt.xlabel('character', size=15)
plt.ylabel('counts', size=15)

# plt.xticks(range(len(x)), x)

plt.show()
```

OUTPUT:

[image: out]

Comment: The OP is using a matplotlib version 2.1. See my comment below the question.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Ah, Gotcha